# Why the following joint PDFs are equal: $g(w+z,z)=g(w,z)$?

Tags: probability

I am reading the following book: "Probability and Statistics, 2nd edition, by Morris H. DeGroot".

Chapter 3.9. Functions of two or more random variables:

> Suppose that the variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ form a random sample of
> size $n$ from a distribution for which the p.d.f. is $f$ and the d.f.
> is $F$; consider the random variable $Y_n=\mathrm{max}\{X1,\ldots,
> > X_n\}$ and $Y_1=\mathrm{min}\{X1,\ldots, X_n\}$. Let $g(y_1,y_n)$ and
> $G(y_1,y_n)$ be the joint p.d.f and d.f. of $Y_1$ and $Y_n$,
> respectively. Then
>
> $$G(y_1,y_n)=[F(y_n)]^n-[F(y_n)-F(y_1)]^n,$$
> $$g(y_1,y_n)=n(n-1)[F(y_n)-F(y_1)]^{n-2}f(y_1)f(y_n).$$

I understood this part. But I have the problem with what comes next.

> The random variable $W=Y_n-Y_1$ is called the range. We shell
> determine the p.d.f. of $W$. Let $Y_1=Z$ and $Y_n=W+Z$, then the joint
> p.d.f. of $W$ and $Z$ is
>
> $$g(w,z)=n(n-1)[F(w+z)-F(z)]^{n-2}f(z)f(w+z).$$

If we directly replace $Y_1$ with $Z$ and $Y_n$ with $W+Z$, then we get the following

$$g(w+z,z)=n(n-1)[F(w+z)-F(z)]^{n-2}f(z)f(w+z).$$

Why here $g(w+z,z)$ is equal to $g(w,z)$?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing to get $g(w+z,z)$. You are supposed to put $y_1=w$ and $y_2=z$. Nothing more to be done.  [The notation used is somewhat confusing. Perhaps they should not have written $g(w,z)$ at all and written $g(y_1,y_n)$ instead].

Comment: @geetha290krm wait, but then how to calculate pdf of $W$? They have written $g(w,z)$ so that we can get pdf of $W$.

Comment: You don't get it  immediately. You have to apply the transformation $(x,y) \to (x,y-x)$ and the integrate w.r.t $x$.